# Correct HTML form markup

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

We are having a discussion as I'm currently fixing an IE7 bug, as `<label>` and `<input>` tags were wrapped in a `<p>`.

I cannot seem to find any documentation for the correct semantics for tags contained in a `<form>` tag. I tend to use the following for example,

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="formrow">
      <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

However, looking at the [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/forms.php) they don't wrap any elements at all, perhaps for style, but for `radio` and `checkbox` they put the `<input>` inside the `<label>` which I didn't think was valid. Although the Zurb page is using `HTML5` so perhaps it's valid on there?

The [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms) tends to go with a double wrapped `<div>` approach similar to mine. But again they too, wrap the `radio` and `checkbox` inputs inside the label.

So, to my question, are there any definitive rules for the semantics of elements inside a `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which elements are allowed to be descendants of form elements, I suggest to have a look at the [forms section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) of the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/cover.html) (or go through the equivalent [HTML5 section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#forms)).

For example, [any inline element is allowed inside `<label>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

```
<!ELEMENT LABEL - - (%inline;)* -(LABEL) -- form field label text -->
```

The reason why the `input` elements are inside their `label` elements is that clicking the descriptive text also toggles the state of the checkboxes. Afaik you can achieve the same by setting the `for` attribute properly.

Comment: ..and a form can contain (%block) so I guess you can use whatever! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_fieldset.asp
An example: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_fieldset

Optionally, you can wrap the "description" of the input field into a

```
<label>
```

element.

```
<label for="name_of_inputfield">Name:</label>
```

Note it's good style to making use of the

```
<legend>
```

tag if you're using a

```
<fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample markup is invalid XHTML 1.0, as the fieldset element does not contain the required legend element. In HTML5, it would be correct, but the action="" attribute is disallowed (action attribute value must not be empty).

But in practical terms, the fieldset markup is pointless—the element is useful for grouping fields, but the sample contains no fields outside the group. The div markup is also superfluous, though required by XHTML 1.0 Strict rules. But probably the real forms are different. If you have several “rows,” as the class name “formrow” suggests, then the odds are that a table element is optimal markup.

There are three reasons to wrap a field and her label in a container element: to satisfy HTML 4.01 Strict and XHTML 1.0 Strict rules (which require that anything within a form be wrapped in a block-level container), to make it possible to style them as a whole, and to make it easier to treat them as a unit in client-side scripting. For such wrapping,

- div is a semantically empty element, often convenient
- fieldset might be logical but requires a legend by old rules and by default creates a special kind of border
- p would be OK by HTML5 rules (which interpret the concept of paragraph liberally), but it hardly wins anything as compared with div—rather, it may imply default top and bottom margins that are too large.