# Right and correct markup in html forms

Tags: html, xhtml, html4

## Once upon a time in HTML

---

I was looking W3Fools and find [this paragraph](http://w3fools.com/#html_forms), related to the errors in W3Schools:

> ```
>   <form>  
>     First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />  
>     Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />  
>    </form>
> ```
>
> This code is wrong. Non-block-level elements (such as `<input>`) are
>   not valid  directly inside `<form>` tags until HTML5.

Well, since I always format that way I said to myself "WAIT, I was wrong all this time". And go to validate it to check if it's true. Efectively, this code don't pass the [validation](http://validator.w3.org/).

Then, searching for the correct markup, I found several examples from more reliable sources, but **none of the following examples** passes the validator.

## The bad, the good and the ugly

---

### 1. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

### 2. [Mozilla Network Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input)

In "Examples" section, I have found this:

> **A common use-case senario**
>
> ```
> <!-- A common form that includes input tags -->
> <form action="getform.php" method="get">
>     First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
>      Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br />
>         E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" /><br />
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
> </form>
> ```

### 3. [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/form#Example_A)

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
  <label>Google: <input type="search" name="q"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Search...">
</form>
```

## A Fistful of Codes

---

### More details:

I'm trying to validate the code as HTML fragment, both in HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0.
The recurring error I have found is:

> document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p",
>   "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address",
>   "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

### The question

What is the **correct and valid** markup I should use to make a form?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506644/correct-html-form-markup) was answered redirecting the OP to the form section of [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html). They provided this code:

```
<FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">
   <P>
     <!--...stuff...-->
     <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
   </P>
</FORM>
```

First, it isn't the same code of their [wiki](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/form#Example_A). But nevermind, from I know, the wiki it isn't 100% accurate.... BUT:

- They fix the validation error by enclose all tag in a `<p>`. But *forms are not paragraphs*, it isn't? This code pass validation, but I think that's not very semantic...
- Expert answers you giving to me (thanks!), for the most part, are to enclose the inner tags in a `<fieldset>`, but if I only need one `fieldset` (for example, a form with only one field or self-related fields), is this correct? Might that not be superflous code (because the `fieldset` tags are supposed to enclose similar fields)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct HTML form markup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506644/correct-html-form-markup)

Comment: @Zenith  I haven't seen that question. But, In this case, I must edit mine, because the answer given give me more doubts. Thanks for the link and for notify me the repeated question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fieldset is a block level element that is commonly used in forms. Therefore you could use a fieldset or another block level element like a div.

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<fieldset><legend>My form</legend>
<label>Google: <input type="text" name="q"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Search...">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<div>
<label>Google: <input type="text" name="q"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Search...">
</div>
</form>
```

This probably rarely gets flagged as non valid markup because people tend to a lot of divs to help style forms nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note that these codes only validate in HTML 4.0. `<fieldset>` requires a `<legend>`. And attribute `search` seems not to be valid value.

Comment: Good point. I just copied the code in the example above, but it's always good to check!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with a few of the others in that FieldSet is the best way to group form items together, especially as it really helps with things like screen readers.

I tend to use the following:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="display: none;"></legend>
        <label for="q">Google:</label>
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search...">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I normally don't include the legend, but if it is required for validation, it doesn't necessarily have to be visible ;)

Comment: The point of screen readers is very helpful for me, I work with accesibility and didn't know that (forms are my cross). Thanks!

Comment: Remember to also add the "for" to the labels, as this details which label is for which control. (And feel free to upvote ;))

Answer (score 1):

> This code is wrong. Non-block-level elements (such as `<input>`) are not valid directly inside `<form>` tags until HTML5.

That's not entirely true. They are valid in Transitional DTDs but not Strict DTDs.

> What is the correct and valid markup I should use to make a form?

It depends on the form.

For the examples given, the W3C version is the best. Having a block container in a form doesn't matter (unless it adds useful semantics, or sensible grouping of separate groups of controls). `<label>` elements are excellent.

Comment: Thanks for clearifing first point. W3Fools discredit W3Schools but seems they aren't in right direction too.. I don't know whom to believe. :p

Comment: @Arkana - All sources have bugs (even the specifications), W3Schools just have much more than their fair share. I suggesting taking advice from several sources, then testing and verifying for yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Alohci. That's what I did before asking this question and the results let me completely confused as you can see! Jeje ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to group fields and labels inside the `<fieldset>` tag, which also sounds very semantical to me.

Comment: But, in case you have few labels and inputs, and all are related each others, use only one `<fieldset>`tag it isn't be superflous code? Thanks at all for your answer.